# Where to define a list for with_items: to refere?

Tags: ansible

In the below code where I can define the `traceroute_dest` as a list that Ansible understand to get it from?

```
---
- name : Traceroute ip addresses
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: "Trace multiple ip addresses"
      raw: "traceroute {{item}}"
      register: trace_result
      with_items: "{{'traceroute_dest'}}"
    - debug: var=trace_result.stdout_lines
```

Comment: First try to print "{{traceroute_dest}}" so that you can check. What is coming as input.

Comment: TASK [Trace multiple ip addresses] *********************************************
task path: /Desktop/Python/trace.yml:6
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined Error, in the future this will be a fatal error.: 'traceroute_dest' is undefined.
This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation warnings can be 
disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

Comment: even i removed the quotes from inside , it is still doesn;t know where to look up for traceroute_dest . btw , i created another yaml file that have the traceroute_dest  and name of the file is host_vars.yml. is it a correct approach?

Comment: I have edited you post for that error. Can you please check again? Earlier there were single qoutes  `'traceroute_dest' `.

Comment: Where you have defined `traceroute_dest`?

Comment: in a different host_vars.yml as:

Comment: have you included that yml in this playbook?

Comment: ---
traceroute_dest:
  - '3.4.5.6''
  - '1.2.3.4'

Comment: I will provide you complete YML. On that way can do this.

Comment: perfect  thank you very much. Btw , i thought ansible will know where to look up for variables ? is not that the case?

Comment: I have added an answer. Check whether it is working fine or not. Working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete playbook should be like this.

```
---
- name : Traceroute ip addresses
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - 42266085-vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: "Trace multiple ip addresses"
    raw: "traceroute {{item}}"  
    register: trace_result
    with_items: "{{traceroute_dest}}"
  - debug: var=trace_result
...
```

Files where variables are defined should be like this.

```
---
traceroute_dest: ["119.82.76.111"]
```

Comment: thank you very much and may i ask you what is the best way of making the traceroute outputs more readable?

Comment: @NANIS I will suggest you but what is your expected format?

Comment: because of security reasons i am not able paste my output but it is not regular output . It has lots of stdout lines with \r \n and etc. i would like to get the regular traceroute output only the number of hops and ip addresses.